# Is django-ckeditor a truly wysiwyg editor?

Tags: django, python-3.x, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x, django-ckeditor

When I'm editing content in ckeditor, it looks great with all the styling applied. For example, code snippet looks like:

[image: ckeditor editor content.]

and blockquote looks like: 
[image: content displayed in browser]

But when django template(content) is rendered it doesn't preserve any of the styling.

Code snippets becomes :[image: content displayed inside ckeditor]

and blockquote becomes :
[image: content displayed in browser]

Comment: You probably need to include a CSS file for the rendered content?

Comment: But that css works only on `textarea` with some `id`. I added all the css files manually but none worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the styles in CKEditor are also available in your site's CSS files. See `contents.css` in CKEditor's main folder and adjust both it, and/or your site's CSS, to match each other.